# Unresolved external symbol linker errors when including stb_image.h

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

I get the following errors:

[image: Error List screenshot]

> - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol `_stbi_load` referenced in function `_main`
> - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol `_stbi_image_free` referenced in function `_main`
>   LNK 1120 2 unresolved externals

Initially, I gave the path of the `stb_image.h` & `stb_image.c` file location C/C++ include directories, as adding the header file directly to the project was not working.

Comment: Does [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088002/stb-image-h-in-visual-studio-unresolved-external-symbol) fix your problem?

Comment: Include your errors as text, not as images. This keeps the exact error message searchable, and accessible for users using screen readers.

Comment: hey @user1118321 i have done that already yet i get the same error, the weird part is when i try load the stb_image.h file -> add as an existing item i get this error "cannot open source file stb_image.h" at this step #include <stb_image.h> and i made sure i had the #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION.

Comment: solved it apparently adding the header file to the VC++ include directory solves the issue. Phew thanks guyz.

Comment: Publish an answer to your question with the solution and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Add:
`#define STB_IMAGE_IMEPLEMENTATION`

And after that add: 
`#include stb_image.h`

I had also faced same issue but this define solved it.